# Error 10038 (Socket operation on invalid socket) when trying to send a string from Winsock2 C program

Tags: c, sockets, client, winsock, winsock2

I'm trying to make a C library that mimics Python socket library.

When i run my main function, an error occurs on `simplesend(sucket, "foo");`

the whole main function:

```
int main(){
    struct SIMPLESOCKET sucket;

    simpleinit(sucket);

    simpleconnect(sucket, "ip", "port");

    simplesend(sucket, "foo");
    
    simpleclose(sucket);
    
    return 0;
}
```

this is the definition of the SIMPLESOCKET struct:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

struct SIMPLESOCKET{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    struct addrinfo *result;
    struct addrinfo *ptr;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket;
};
```

I get error 10038, which is "socket operation on invalid socket". But when i check s.ConnectSocket, it isn't equal to `INVALID_SOCKET`.

the simplesend function body:

```
int simplesend(struct SIMPLESOCKET s, char* msg){

    s.iResult = send(s.ConnectSocket, msg, (int) strlen(msg), 0);
    if (s.iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s.ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and the only part of the code that does stuff to `s.ConnectSocket` doesnt give any errors, here it is:

```
int simpleconnect(struct SIMPLESOCKET s, char* ip, char* port){
    memset(&s.hints, 0, sizeof(s.hints));
    s.iResult = getaddrinfo(ip, port, &s.hints, &s.result);
    if (s.iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", s.iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    s.ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    s.ptr=s.result;
    s.ConnectSocket = socket(s.ptr->ai_family, s.ptr->ai_socktype, s.ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (s.ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(s.result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //connect
    s.iResult = connect(s.ConnectSocket, s.ptr->ai_addr, (int)s.ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (s.iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("1977\n");
        closesocket(s.ConnectSocket);
        s.ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    
    freeaddrinfo(s.result);
    if (s.ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("unable to connect to server\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

So, i really don't understand why i get an invalid socket error since i even get the successfull connection on my python server.

Comment: Remember that arguments to functions are passed *by value*. That means the value of the argument is *copied* when you call the function. The function only have a copy in its own local argument variable. Modifying this copy will of course not modify the original value used in the call. Now think about that in relation to the `simpleinit` and `simpleconnect` functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm kinda new to C and i completely forgot that. I fixed now and it works